# Finder displays "Create PDF" option for SVG file, but when I select it nothing happens

Tags: macos, finder, catalina

The Finder displays a "Create PDF" option when I select a SVG file, but, when I select it, it does nothing.

Does anybody know how to use this feature?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It seems to be a bug, I can confirm this issue in macOS Catalina 10.15.6 (19G2021).

Answer (score 1):

macOS (at least as of Catalina) does not natively convert SVG to PDF. The simplest workaround is to open the SVG in Safari and then "Export to PDF..." from there.

Comment: so "Create PDF" is use less?

Comment: @SPatel "Create PDF" works on PNG and JPG images.

Comment: The bug is that the "Create PDF" Quick Action appears for this filetype, which is not one of MacOS's native graphics types: TIFF, PNG, JPEG, PDF, etc, etc.